# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such service ComponentInfo{/com.SampleApp.AttendanceApp.ServiceClass}

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android to build an app which should allow the app to keep sending a driver's location every 15 minutes so that I can keep track of his movement. I used `JobScheduler` to get this done. My project is very simple now and only contains the following 3 files:

1. `MainActivity.cs`
2. `AttendancePage.cs` (Content page, interact with UI button to start the service)
3. `ServiceClass.cs`

**Methods in Main Activity.cs**

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        scheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
        LoadApplication(new App());   //This line will then jump to AttendancePage.cs
    }

    public void ScheduleJob()
    {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(ServiceClass)));
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
            .SetPersisted(true)
            .SetPeriodic(60000)
            .Build();

        int resultCode = scheduler.Schedule(info);  //The error show when hit this line.

        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.ResultSuccess)
        {
            Log.Info("Message", "Job Schedule!");
        }
        else
        {
            Log.Info("Message", "Job shceduling failed");
        }
    }

    public void CancelJob()
    {
        scheduler.Cancel(123);
    }
```

**AttendancePage.cs**

```
public partial class AttendancePage : ContentPage
{
    MainActivity main = new MainActivity();

    public AttendancePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Attendance App";           
    }

    //Button OnClickEvent
    async void ScheduleJob(object s, EventArgs e)
    {           
        main.ScheduleJob();              
    }

    //Button OnClickEvent
    async void CancelJob(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        main.CancelJob();
    }
}
```

**ServiceClass.cs**

```
[Service(Name = "com.SampleApp.AttendanceApp.ServiceClass", Permission = "android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE")]
public class ServiceClass : JobService
{
    public ServiceClass()
    {

    }

    public override bool OnStartJob(JobParameters jobParamsOnStart)
    {
        doBackgroundWork(jobParamsOnStart);
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(JobParameters jobParam)
    {
        //My code to send driver's location
        TestingPage.GetGPS();

        JobFinished(jobParam, false);
    }

    public override bool OnStopJob(JobParameters jobParamsOnStop)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have added the service tag inside AndroidManifest.xml as well.

```
<service android:name=".ServiceClass"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" 
    android:exported="true" />
```

I have no idea why the error is still there. The error is from the line scheduler.Schedule(JobInfo). Anyone has another possible solution? I am frustrated on solving this. Will the reason be I can't debug on the service but only can straight away run in release mode? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Froms shared code it works in Xamarin.Android project , however here is a Xamarin.Forms project . It can not work.

In **AttendancePage.cs** , you create a new `MainActivity` to invoke the native method `ScheduleJob` and `CancelJob` . This will not find the **JobScheduler** in native ,then it will return null .

> No such service ComponentInfo{/com.SampleApp.AttendanceApp.ServiceClass}

If you want to invoke native method , you can have a try with [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) in Xamarin Forms .

At least need to create a `Interface` in Forms to invoke :

```
public interface IJobSchedulerService 
{
    //Start JobSchedule
    void StartJobSchedule();

    //Cancel JobSchedule
    void CancelJobSchedule();
}
```

Then can invoke in Xamarin Forms as follow :

```
async void ScheduleJob(object s, EventArgs e)
{           
    DependencyService.Get<IJobSchedulerService>().StartJobSchedule();              
}

//Button OnClickEvent
async void CancelJob(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    DependencyService.Get<IJobSchedulerService>().CancelJobSchedule();
}
```

Now you need to implement the `IJobSchedulerService` in native android .Create the  **JobSchedulerDependcenyService**:

```
public class JobSchedulerDependcenyService : IJobSchedulerService
{
    JobScheduler jobScheduler;

    public JobSchedulerDependcenyService()
    {
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)MainActivity.Instance.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.JobSchedulerService);
    }

    public void StartJobSchedule()
    {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(MainActivity.Instance, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(DownloadJob)));
        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1, componentName)
            .SetOverrideDeadline(0)
            .Build();

        //var jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)GetSystemService(JobSchedulerService);
        var scheduleResult = jobScheduler.Schedule(jobInfo);

        if (JobScheduler.ResultSuccess == scheduleResult)
        {
            var snackBar = Snackbar.Make(MainActivity.Instance.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content), "jobscheduled_success", Snackbar.LengthShort);
            snackBar.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            var snackBar = Snackbar.Make(MainActivity.Instance.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content), "jobscheduled_failure", Snackbar.LengthShort);
            snackBar.Show();
        }

    }

    public void CancelJobSchedule()
    {
        jobScheduler.CancelAll();
    }
}
```

Here you will find the `MainActivity.Instance` inside it , that's a static instance defined by self in `MainActivity`.

```
    public static MainActivity Instance { set; get; }
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Instance = this;

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
```